# Braces "{}" inserted into message text when using telegram-cli

Tags: linux, bash, telegram

I have a script to send a message using telegram-cli. The message is sent well, the only problem is that the message has those "brackets" between the message, it means, some like this:

```
{Hola Mundo}
```

Then, when I want to send a message I use this script like this:

```
./script_telegram.sh "Hola Mundo"
```

And when the message arrives, it has "{}" between message.

Any suggestion?

Comment: please post script_telegram

Answer (score -1):

use this one script to send telegram messages

https://github.com/fabianonline/telegram.sh.git

```
./telegram -t "TOKEN_123" -c "CHAT_ID_123" message
```

It sends the proper message without brackets.